# How to convert tabular format data to sentence or readable format using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

[Here is the table format in image so how should i convert it into readable format like it should display as-
member_id is  belongs to region and so on for other columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KnSu.png)

So, can anyone help me out how to write a function to convert tabular format data to readable sentence format?

Comment: you can use concat and string literals to achieve what you want. this question can be researched very easily.like F.concat(F.col("member_id"),F.lit(" resides in "), F.col("address"))

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column named "`Sentence`" like below and convert into a readable format using `concat` function. I have also writing df into a file if you want it into CSV file.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.show()
+-----+---------+---+----+
|fname|    lname|age|dept|
+-----+---------+---+----+
| Jack|  Felice | 25|  IT|
| Mike| Gilbert | 30|  CS|
| John|     Shen| 45|  DR|
+-----+---------+---+----+

>>> df1 = df.withColumn("sentence", concat( col("fname"), lit(" "), col("lname"), lit("is "), col("age"), lit(" year's old and he works in a "), col("dept"), lit(" department."))).select("sentence")
>>> df1.show(10,False)
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|sentence                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|Jack Felice is 25 year's old and he works in a IT department.  |
|Mike  Gilbert is 30 year's old and he works in a CS department.|
|John Shenis 45 year's old and he works in a DR department.     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+

>>> df1.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save("/out/")
```

**CSV Output**

[image]

Comment: Actually i don't want to create extra column as sentence instead i want to display table data in sentence format.

Comment: I was trying to take input as user_id and based on input i want to display table data but why its not displaying anything in output. The code i wrote was-    val = input("Enter user_id: ")
df.select(['user_id','date','city']).orderBy(col('date'), ascending=True).where((col('User_id')==val)).show() .        Can anyone help me out how to figure out this?

Comment: you can overwrite existing dataframe column also if you do not want to add new column.

Comment: about your second comment, I think that is different issue so please ask another question at StackOverflow.

Comment: suppose i have to take input as range of date(from date and to date) and how should it display/fetch required data from table to sentence format. Also like how to give range of dates?